How to set default values for pickStringRemember and promptStringRemember in VSCode?
I'm unable to set default values for input variables of type pickStringRemember and promptStringRemember in VSCode with the "Command Variable"-Extension (v1.63.0)
I successfully passed input variables from launch.json to task.json in VSCode with the following configuration:
launch.json:
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Program",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/app.js ${input:ChooseModule} ${input:ChooseBaseNode}",
            "preLaunchTask": "Build"
        },
    ],
    "inputs": [
        {
            "id": "ChooseModule",
            "type": "command",
            "command": "extension.commandvariable.pickStringRemember",
            "args": {
                "key": "Module",
                "options": [
                    "ModuleA.py",
                    "ModuleB.py",
                    "ModuleC.py",
                ],
                "description": "Choose a Module"
            },
        },
        {
            "id": "ChooseBaseNode",
            "type": "command",
            "command": "extension.commandvariable.promptStringRemember",
            "args": {
                "key": "BaseNode",
                "description": "Base node",
            }
        },
    ]
}

task.json:
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
      {
        "label": "Build",
        "type": "shell",
        "command": "python",
        "args": [ "build.py", "${input:ChooseModule}", "${input:ChooseBaseNode}" ],
      },
    ],
    "inputs": [
        {
            "id": "ChooseModule",
            "type": "command",
            "command": "extension.commandvariable.remember",
            "args": {
                "key": "Module",
            }
        },
        {
            "id": "ChooseBaseNode",
            "type": "command",
            "command": "extension.commandvariable.remember",
            "args": {
                "key": "BaseNode"
            }
        }
    ]
}


Launching the program, selecting "ModuleA" as Module and entering "Node1" as Node results in the line
"Executing task: python build.py ModuleA.py Node1"
in the Terminal, so the variables are passed successfully!!
Now I tried to set "ModuleC.py" and "Node2" as default values for the pick and the prompt with the following changes:
task.json:
                ...
                "options": [
                    "ModuleA.py",
                    "ModuleB.py",
                    "ModuleC.py",
                ],
                "default": "ModuleC.py",
                "description": "Choose a Module"
                ...

            ...
                "key": "BaseNode",
                "default": "Node2"
                "description": "Base node",
            ...


I expected to see the "ModuleC" item selected and on top of the pick-list (as it works with plain "pickString") and "Node2" selected and entered in the input field. But that's not the case! Neither the pick-list nor the input field shows and accepts the default values.
Whats wrong with my code ?
